# Replacement 100 ohm resistor for differential scope probe?

Tags: oscilloscope, differential, probe, tektronix

I'm trying to use a P7504 ($$$) "TriMode" scope probe, and unfortunately the resistors eventually break. Does anyone have recommendations for a 100ohm resistor that would replace the ones on the probe? A new set of just ends is $1600
[image]

Comment: For a $1600 probe? Might as well go with the best and I don't know resistors that are more precise or stable than metal foil resistors.

Comment: I have used a similar Tek probe. For a 4 GHz probe, many parameters of the resistor may be critical. If I was making critical measurements, I would only use the exact resistor.

Comment: Yes, that is why I reached out to ask what resistors are ideal to replace the ones on the probe :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a 4GHz probe. [This](https://www.vishay.com/docs/60107/freqresp.pdf) Vishay app note on high frequency parasitics may be of use.

[image]

One could imagine attaching wires to an 0402 resistor and adding a bit of epoxy... but..

A set of 50 ea. 100 ohm + 50 ea. 75 ohm appears to be a mere $700 from Tektronix. 020-2937-00

Comment: Thank you, Spehro - half the price of the probe kit for 50 of the resistors we actually need sounds more in-line with what we need. Hopefully this helps someone else, too